# How in Corona make distinction between click and long click?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How in Corona make distinction between click and long click ?
I want on click to move next scene and in case of long click to show some data ( while user holding finger on that button ) and not to move on next scene. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating 2 event handlers:

- One for tap event for moving to the next scene
- One for touch event to show some data. In the touch event handlers, have a condition checking the
  current phase of the event so that you show the data on "began"
  phase, hide the data on "ended" phase

Example:

```
function object:touch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
       -- Show data
    elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
       -- Hide data
    end
    return true
end
```

Details about touch event:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/phase.html

Answer (score 0):

This is actually tricky because the touch handler must only show the data if the user touches for *more* than a certain amount of time. But if the user does not move finger while they are touching then the event handler will not get called between the began and ended phases so you don't get a chance to make data visible.

Therefore you must start a timer in the began phase with a callback to a function that makes the data visible. In the ended phase you cancel the timer so that if the touch didn't last long enough, the data display callback will not get called. Also in this phase you set the data visibility to false so that regardless of timer, the data is sure to no longer be visible upon release of touch.

I can show some code when I get access to my desktop.